# ls *.* gives: "*.*: No such file or directory" message

Tags: sudo, ls, wildcards

I'm using Linux app-server 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux. When I go to a directory with several files named `name1.php`, `name1.html`, `name2.php`, etc. and type:

```
$ sudo ls *.*
```

I get:

```
ls: cannot access *.*: No such file or directory
```

I have the same sort of problem with `grep`:

```
$ grep "TOS.html" *.*
grep: *.*: No such file or directory
```

Why is that and how do I get around this problem?

#### Edit #1:

```
$ shopt | grep glob
+ grep glob
+ shopt
dotglob         off
extglob         on
failglob        off
globstar        off
nocaseglob      off
nullglob        off
```

#### Edit #2:

```
$ ls -ld;echo --;sudo ls -ld 
+ ls --color=auto -ld
drwxr-x--x 16 www-data root 12288 Oct 10 17:08 .
+ echo --
--
+ sudo ls -ld
drwxr-x--x 16 www-data root 12288 Oct 10 17:08 .
```

Comment: Which shell are you using? `*.*` usually expands to all files that have a dot (except the ones starting with a dot). `*.* no such file` would be when there is no file with dot, or you quoted the `"*"` to mean a literal asterisk instead.

Comment: There are a lot of files with a dot.  For example TOS.php

Comment: I get the same with "sudo ls *".  That is "ls: cannot access *: No such file or directory".

Comment: What do you get if you `set -x` before running a command with a glob pattern?

Comment: I typed "set -x" followed by "set +o noglob" followed by "sudo ls *"  and got "+ sudo ls '*'" (new line) "ls: cannot access *: No such file or directory"

Comment: @OtagoHarbour Hmm... Can you please update your question with the output of `shopt | grep glob`?

Comment: Hi Joseph.  I have made that edit.  Thanks.

Comment: what do you get with ls -ld;echo --;sudo ls -ld

Comment: Are the "files" broken symlinks?

Comment: Hildred.  I made the edit (Edit 2).  Thanks.

Comment: @jordanm.  No they are actual files, not symlinks.

Comment: It's nice that you listed `ls -ld .`; however, the key information that is missing is: who are you? Output of `id`. The directory is not readable to users who are not `www-data`, or who are not in group 0, `root`. The directory is searchable, which means files can be accessed if you know the exact name. But the directory cannot be listed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Background

I think your issue is ultimately because of these permissions on that directory:

```
drwxr-x--x 16 www-data root 12288 Oct 10 17:08 .
```

Notice that the owner (`www-data`) and the group (`root`) have `rwx` and `r-x` respectively. However notice that the other permissions are set to just `--x`.

This means that you can execute commands in this directory, but you cannot read or perform listings of the contents of this directory.

#### Your scenario

You're some other user (not `www-data`), when you run the `sudo` command while in this directory. Let's call this user, UserX.

When the shell invokes this command as UserX:

```
$ sudo ls *.*
```

and returns this:

```
ls: cannot access *.*: No such file or directory
```

UserX's shell tried to expand the `*.*` to any files, but because UserX cannot read any of the contents of this directory it returns nothing. You're then sending a literal `*.*` to the `sudo ls *.*` which fails to match any literal files named `*.*`.

The same problem occurs when you attempt to perform the `grep` command too. Again UserX cannot read any of the files and so you're instructing `grep` to search for a literal file, `*.*`, and it's finding no files by that name. Hence the messages:

> cannot access *.*: No such file or directory

and

> *.*: No such file or directory

#### Example

Say we have the following setup, like yours.

```
$ sudo chown nginx.root /tmp/afolder
$ sudo chmod 751 /tmp/afolder/
$ sudo ls -ld /tmp/afolder/
drwxr-x--x 2 nginx root 4096 Nov 23 04:10 /tmp/afolder/
$ sudo touch /tmp/afolder/fakefile.txt
```

Now let's become "UserX", in my case it's `saml`:

```
$ id
uid=500(saml) gid=501(saml) groups=501(saml)
```

I can cd into the directory:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/afolder
```

But when I attempt to list the files in this directory:

```
$ ls *
ls: cannot access *: No such file or directory
```

Same problems with `sudo`:

```
$ sudo ls -l *.*
ls: cannot access *.*: No such file or directory
```

Invoking a shell and protecting the expansion of the `*` with single quotes can get what you want:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'ls -l *.*'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 23 04:14 fakefile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I very much appreciated your explanation and your solution fixed the problem as well.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
sudo sh -c 'ls -l *.*'
```